# Dimention and disksize for Images downloaded from web on android apps

Tags: android, image, gridview

In a app, I show list of images in a gird-view. These images are downloaded from my website. When a specific image is selected next page shows a close to full-screen size version of that selected image.

My plan is to create 256x256px images (30-40 KB) for girdview and 512x512px (100-150kb)images for full-screen version. I am not asking about icon sizes(this i already know). This is related to images downloaded to phone or tablet.

Is this a good plan? am I doing something wrong when different devices are considered? How can I improve this for performance, especially the gridview images.  I am using Picasso api for image download and scaling.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    Download Image and get bitmap.
    Now resize bitmap used following method as per your require you car resize bitmap.
   private Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
        try {
            int newwidth = 0, newheight = 0;
            Log.i("image size", "Height= " + bm.getHeight() + "width= " + bm.getWidth());
            if (bm.getWidth() > 400 || bm.getHeight() > 700) {
                newwidth = bm.getWidth();
                newheight = bm.getHeight();
                for (int i = 0; newwidth > 400 || newheight > 700; i++) {
                    newwidth = (int) (newwidth / 1.25f);
                    newheight = (int) (newheight / 1.25f);
                }
                Bitmap result = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, newwidth, newheight, false);
                bm.recycle();
                bm = null;
                return result;
            } else {
                return bm;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am already doing resizing. What I am worried about is the Dimentions I have selected and approach I have taken. are they good enough for all phones and tablets. Are there any other thing I have to consider